# Appstore rejected app because of ApplePay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've implemented ApplePay and appstore rejected my app:
This is what Apple have written back:

Your app uses Apple Pay as a purchasing mechanism but does not use Apple Pay branding and user interface elements appropriately as described in the Apple Pay Human Interface Guidelines.

- Specifically:

Your app acts as an intermediary between users and a third-party business, but the business receiving the payment is not specified on the payment sheet.

- Next Steps:

Please revise Apple Pay implementation in your app so that it is compliant with all the App Store Review Guidelines and the Apple Pay Human Interface Guidelines.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Que!?  What's the question?

Comment: How you are using Apple Pay?

Comment: How i can resolve this issue ? @ElTomato

Comment: @SaqibOmer i am using shopify sdk

Comment: You have written "the business receiving the payment is not specified on the payment sheet."  If that's not clear enough, talk to your reviewer.

Comment: When you use Apple Pay, you need to specify who will be receiving payment. Add UI like "Pay 20 USD to JohnDoeStore". Also create a video of payment process and add in attachment for review on itunesconnect.

Comment: @SaqibOmer i attached screenshot

Comment: @AnilKumar, How exactly you are paying to another store from your app, are you using any third party for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Apple [Human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/checkout-and-payment/), sheet should contain end merchant name.

Format:

```
PAY [COMPANY_NAME]

OR

// If your app or website acts as an intermediary and isn’t the end merchant for a payment
PAY [END_MERCHANT_NAME] (VIA [YOUR_APP_OR_WEBSITE_NAME]).
```

Reviewer understand that, your app acts as an intermediary.
So that format should be as the 2nd one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:

Can you please check this attached screenshot is this correct ?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfn8wi43ijgj8q7/test.png?dl=0

Comment: This is the format. I hope your merchant and appname are different.

Comment: If it's same then, that makes any issue?

Comment: Is your merchant name and Applestore account name is same? Merchant name should the legal name of the business., I think.

Comment: Better way is to directly talk with your reviewer. as I don't know exact titles of your business name.

Comment: Any update from apple team? @AnilKumar

Comment: Client didn’t update me related to this.May be it’s working. Thanks once again.